# Storing Pieces of a String using Strtok

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int menuswitch=1;
    int amountofstudents;
    int fname[50];
    int lname[50];
    int grade[50];
    int i;
    char studentinfo[100];
    printf("Enter Amount of Students: ");
    scanf("%d", &amountofstudents);
    for (i=0;i<amountofstudents;i++)
    {
        gets(studentinfo);
        strcpy(fname[i], strtok(studentinfo, " "));
        strcpy(lname[i], strtok(NULL, " "));
        strcpy(grade[i], strtok(NULL, " "));
    }
```

Alright need a little using strtok. I am trying to store pieces of an input string to sort later. I was thinking of using strtok to break the string then placing each piece in the corresponding array. Yet, every time I try I get an error in Visual Studios saying Access Violation. Thanks for the help ahead of time

The error is

```
First-chance exception at 0x5120F7B3 (msvcr110d.dll) in Lab 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x5120F7B3 (msvcr110d.dll) in Lab 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

The input would be

```
FirstName Lastname 80(Grade)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample input that causes this? And maybe a call stack from a debugger?

Comment: why do you trying to copy `char*` into `int*` vis strcpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem is that you try to copy into *integer values* and not strings. Change the 
integer arrays to arrays of strings:

```
...
char fname[50][100];
char lname[50][100];
char grade[50][100];
...
```

---

You also have a problem with the `gets` function (besides it being obseleted and should not be used), namely that the previous `scanf` doesn't remove the newline from the input buffer so the first `gets` call will see this empty newline and give you an empty line (which you do not check for).

This is simply solved by telling `scanf` to discard trailing whitespace by adding a space in the format string after the `"%d"`:

```
scanf("%d ", &amountofstudents);
/*       ^    */
/*       |    */
/* Note space */
```

Instead of `gets`, you should be using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

```
fgets(studentinfo, sizeof(studentinfo), stdin);
```

And finally, **always** check for errors!

Comment: Sorry about putting the int that was a rookie mistake. Fgets did solve the problem thanks I will be using that from now on

Answer (score 0):

a potential issue is the `scanf/gets combo`. use instead `fgets()` and convert when appropriate to integer using `atoi()` it is also good to do a sanity check on what is returned from strtok *(it is never good to assume anything about input)*

```
char* token = strtok(studentinfo, " ");
if ( strlen(token) < sizeof(fname[i]) )
{
  strcpy(fname[i], token);
...
```

you have also declared your strings as integer arrays, they should be char
e.g. `char fname[50];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you have declared three variables (fname, lname, and grade) as char[] (arrays) (well, that is the type you meant to use), but you want to prompt for and keep around a bunch of students information.  And you later try to copy from strtok() into what you want to be a char[], but since you dereferenced fname[i] (lname[i], grade[i]), they are of type char, rather than char[].

You will need stdlib.h for exit,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit
#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h> //you don't need this, yet
#define STUDLIMIT (100)
```

You can either create an array of fname[], lname[], grade[], (see here: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html),

```
int main(void)
{
    //int menuswitch=1; //you aren't using this
    int amountofstudents;
    char studentinfo[100];
    char fname[STUDLIMIT][50];
    char lname[STUDLIMIT][50];
    char grade[STUDLIMIT][50];
    int ndx;
    printf("Enter Amount of Students: ");
    if( (fscanf(stdin,"%d ", &amountofstudents)<=0)
    || (amountofstudents<1) || (amountofstudents>STUDLIMIT) )
    {
        printf("need %d to %d studends\n",1,STUDLIMIT); exit(0);
    }
    for (ndx=0;ndx<amountofstudents;ndx++)
    {
        printf("Student: "); fflush(stdout);
        fgets(studentinfo,sizeof(studentinfo),stdin);
        strcpy(fname[ndx], strtok(studentinfo, " "));
        strcpy(lname[ndx], strtok(NULL, " "));
        strcpy(grade[ndx], strtok(NULL, " "));
    }
}
```

Or you can create a struct(ure) to hold the entered student information, and instantiate an array of these student records, one for each student you enter and store,

```
typedef struct student
{
    char fname[50];
    char lname[50];
    char grade[50];
} StudentObj;
int StudentCopy(StudentObj*sp,char*fname,char*lname,char*grade)
{
    if(!sp || !fname || !lname || !grade ) return -1;
    strcpy(sp->fname, fname);
    strcpy(sp->fname, lname);
    strcpy(sp->fname, grade);
}
StudentObj students[STUDLIMIT];
int main(void)
{
    //int menuswitch=1; //you aren't using this
    int amountofstudents;
    char studentinfo[100];
    char fname[50];
    char lname[50];
    char grade[50];
    int ndx;
    printf("Enter Amount of Students: ");
    if( (fscanf(stdin,"%d ",&amountofstudents)<=0)
    || (amountofstudents<1) || (amountofstudents>STUDLIMIT) )
    {
        printf("need %d to %d studends\n",1,STUDLIMIT); exit(0);
    }
    for (ndx=0;ndx<amountofstudents;ndx++)
    {
        printf("Student: "); fflush(stdout);
        fgets(studentinfo,sizeof(studentinfo),stdin);
        strcpy(fname, strtok(studentinfo, " "));
        strcpy(lname, strtok(NULL, " "));
        strcpy(grade, strtok(NULL, " \n\r"));
        StudentCopy(&(students[ndx]),fname,lname,grade);
    }
}
```